# Not able to import python files needed in main.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory-structure

I have this file structure which i am not too sure is considered good practice.
here is the directory structure

[image: my projects file structure]

I am trying to import the content of *seed.py* and *wallet_generation.py* into my *main.py* file.
But when I try import the files through a relative path ie (../../bitcoinBackend/seed and ../../bitcoinBackend/wallet_generation) I get errors where the files are not recognized.

Im assuming that my file structure will need some cleaning up, but if ye have any tips on how I should rearrange my file structure or on how to properly import these 2 python files id greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: The error message is just a *ModuleNotFoundError*

Comment: I come from a java background myself so I'm having a lot of difficulty trying to figure out where I'm going wrong

Comment: Can you post the error messages? Also, why is your project *within* the venv folder?

Comment: I added the error message to the post there, and i dont know tbh, I thought I had to put it in the venv folder, is this bad practise?, should i move the bitcoinbackend and front end folders to the top level?

Comment: venv is similar to .git, you shouldn't be putting any of your files there. You should move both folders to the top level instead.

Comment: will do, thanks for the advice. Should hopefully help in cleaning up my file structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) a try.

In practice, in `main.py`, you could import `wallet_generation` like so:

```
from ...bitcoinBackend.locales import wallet_generation
```

Roughly speaking, if you call `main.py` as part of a package, then:

- `..` will refer to the parent directory of `main.py`
- `...` will refer to the 2nd parent directory of `main.py`
- `.` would refer to the directory in which `main.py` is

Comment: Worked on first try, cheers. I had no idea parent directory's and 2nd parent directory's had that kind of syntax

Comment: ive been getting this new error since I got the relative imports working "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" have you any idea how to fix this?